# Issue implementing Sql_tracker_store

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I want to use sql tracker store to store the conversation history in db but it seems it is not working for me.
I am having MySQL database which i want to connect for that i am using below code in my endpoint.yml

```
tracker_store:
    type: SQL
    dialect: "sqlite"  # the dialect used to interact with the db
    url: "localhost"  # (optional) host of the sql db
    db: "chatbot"  # path to your db
    username: "root"  # username used for authentication
    password: "test"  # password used for authentication
```

when i am running `rasa shell -m models --endpoints endpoints.yml`
i am getting below error.

```
" sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db" % (url,)
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid SQLite URL: sqlite://root:test@localhost/c
hatbot
Valid SQLite URL forms are:
 sqlite:///:memory: (or, sqlite://)
 sqlite:///relative/path/to/file.db
 sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db
```

When i tried to connect the same db using python code it worked for me. Below is my python code.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",port="3306",user="root",database="chatbot",password="test")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "Show tables;"

mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

Please help me how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `dialect` to use MySQL and `db` to include the `.db` suffix in your `endpoint.yml`:

```
tracker_store:
    type: SQL
    dialect: "mysql"  # the dialect used to interact with the db
    url: somewhere    
    db: "chatbot.db"  
    username: "root"  
    password: "test"
```

More info in the [SQLALchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#mysql) docs

Comment: i tried changing the configuration according to your suggestion. turns out it is not working. when i am using .db it is not able to find the database.

Comment: `.db` suffix is definitely not required (unsure if it actually breaks it). Downvoting as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pymysql using pip.

```
    tracker_store:
        type: SQL
        dialect: "mysql+pymysql"
        url: "localhost"
        db: "Rasabot"
        username: "root"
        password: "xyz"
```